# fixing image coordinate inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to fix the images coordinate so it wont go outside the canvas border, but I can't find a good solution.

This is what I have:

```
function update(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 38) { //going up
        if (py - speed < 0) {
            py = speed; return
        }
        py -= speed;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //going left
        if (px < speed) {
            px = speed;
            return;
        }
        px -= speed;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) { //going down
        if (py > ch-(ph+speed)) {
            py = ch-(ph-speed); return
        }
        py += speed;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 39) { //going right
        if (px+pw > cw ) {
            px = (cw - pw); 
            return
        }
        px += speed;
    }
    $("#position").html(px + " " + py);
    render();
}
```

Here is my js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phjUL/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply clamp `px` and `py` to a given range *after* you applied all changes to them. Eg. right before you call `render` in your update method, clamp your values like this:

```
// this will clamp px to a value between 0 and cw (canvas width)
px = Math.max(0, Math.min(px, cw));

// clamp py to a value between 0 and canvas height
py = Math.max(0, Math.min(py, ch));
```

Your update method will then look like this:

```
function update(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) { //going up
        py -= speed;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) { //going left
        px -= speed;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) { //going down
        py += speed;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) { //going right
        px += speed;
    }
    px = Math.max(0, Math.min(px, cw));
    py = Math.max(0, Math.min(py, ch));
    $("#position").html(px + " " + py);
    render();
}
```

Link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phjUL/4/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think the best way is to</strike> move it first then check if it's out of bounds and move it back. http://jsfiddle.net/phjUL/3/

```
        function update(event) {

            if (event.keyCode == 38) { //going up
                py -= speed;
                if(py < 0) {
                    py = 0;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 37) { //going left
                px -= speed;
                if(px < 0) {
                    px = 0;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 40) { //going down
                py += speed;
                if(py > ch - ph) {
                    py = ch - ph;
                }
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 39) { //going right
                px += speed;
                if(px > cw - pw) {
                    px = cw - pw;
                }
            }

            $("#position").html(px + ", " + py);
            render();
        }
```